# Why is ball widget getting deflected before getting collided by rectangle widget in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am working on one gaming app in which I need the ball widget to get deflected at the angle of 90 to the direction of movement by the rectangle widget after getting collided. In the below code the ball is doing what I said above but it is getting deflected some distance before colliding the rectangle. It would due to the functioning of collide_widget() in the code, Please help to solve this issue!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Rotate, Rectangle, Ellipse, Color
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, CardTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ListProperty, 
DictProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import PopMatrix, PushMatrix

Builder.load_string('''

<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,1,1
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<Game>:
    ball: pong_ball
    object: Object
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":2.6,"y":0}
            size_hint: 3, 1
            text:"Throw"
            background_color: 2,1,190,1
            border: 30,30,30,30
            on_release:
                root.start()

        Button:
            pos_hint:{'x':7.3, 'y':5.3}
            size_hint: 0.5,0.5
            text:'restart'
            on_release:
                root.serve_ball()

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.center

    Object:
        id: Object
        center: self.rotate_origin

<Game1>:
    ball: pong_ball
    object1: Object1
    object2: Object2
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":2.6,"y":0}
            size_hint: 3, 1
            text:"Throw"
            background_color: 2,1,190,1
            border: 30,30,30,30
            on_release:
                root.start()

        Button:
            pos_hint:{'x':7.3, 'y':5.3}
            size_hint: 0.5,0.5
            text:'restart'
            on_release:
                root.serve_ball()

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.center

    Object1:
        id: Object1
        center: self.rotate_origin
    Object2:
        id: Object2
        center: self.rotate_origin

<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager

    Screen:
        name:"P"
        FloatLayout:

            Button:
                pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0.05}
                size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
                text: "Play"
                background_color: 255,0,1,1
                on_release:
                    root.transition.direction = "up";s3.serve_ball()        
                    root.current = "again"

    Screen:
        name: 'again'
        Game1:
            id:s3

''')

class Object(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.rect_pos_x = 500
        self.rect_pos_y = 370
        self.rect_pos = self.rect_pos_x, self.rect_pos_y
        self.rect_width = 200
        self.rect_height = 30
        self.rect_size = self.rect_width, self.rect_height
        self.rotate_origin_x = self.rect_pos_x + self.rect_width / 2
        self.rotate_origin_y = self.rect_pos_y + self.rect_height / 2
        self.rotate_origin = self.rotate_origin_x, self.rotate_origin_y
        self.angle = 135
        print('rect 1')
        with self.canvas:
            PushMatrix()
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0,197,68))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)
            PopMatrix()

    def rotate(self):
        self.canvas.clear()
        self.angle += 90
        if (self.angle > 315):
            self.angle = 225
        with self.canvas:
            PushMatrix()
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0, 255, 100))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)
            PopMatrix()

    def deflect_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            if not ball.collided:
                vx, vy = ball.velocity
                if self.angle == 135:
                    ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(90)
                if self.angle == 225:
                    ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(270)
                if self.angle == 315:
                    ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(90)
                ball.collided = True
        else:
            ball.collided = False


    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.rotate()
            print(self.angle)

class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)
    collided = DictProperty(False)


    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos

class Game(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    object = ObjectProperty(None)

    def start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(5, 0)):
        Clock.unschedule(self.update)
        self.ball.center = 40, 380
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()
        self.object.deflect_ball(self.ball)

        if (self.ball.y < self.y+50) or self.ball.y > 500:
            self.ball.velocity_y = 0
            Clock.unschedule(self.update)
            print('tested')
            self.serve_ball()
            sm.current= 'again'

class Object1(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.rect_pos_x = 500
        self.rect_pos_y = 400
        self.rect_pos = self.rect_pos_x, self.rect_pos_y
        self.rect_width = 200
        self.rect_height = 30
        self.rect_size = self.rect_width, self.rect_height
        self.rotate_origin_x = self.rect_pos_x + self.rect_width / 2
        self.rotate_origin_y = self.rect_pos_y + self.rect_height / 2
        self.rotate_origin = self.rotate_origin_x, self.rotate_origin_y
        self.angle = 135
        print('rect 1')
        with self.canvas:
            PushMatrix()
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0,197,68))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)
            PopMatrix()

    def rotate(self):
        self.canvas.clear()
        self.angle += 90
        if (self.angle > 315):
            self.angle = 225
        with self.canvas:
            PushMatrix()
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0, 255, 100))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)
            PopMatrix()

    def deflect_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            if not ball.collided[self]:
                vx, vy = ball.velocity
                if self.angle == 135:
                    ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(90)
                if self.angle == 225:
                    ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(270)
                if self.angle == 315:
                    ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(90)
                ball.collided[self] = True
        else:
            ball.collided[self] = False


    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.rotate()
            print(self.angle)

class Object2(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.rect_pos_x = 500
        self.rect_pos_y = 170
        self.rect_pos = self.rect_pos_x, self.rect_pos_y
        self.rect_width = 200
        self.rect_height = 30
        self.rect_size = self.rect_width, self.rect_height
        self.rotate_origin_x = self.rect_pos_x + self.rect_width / 2
        self.rotate_origin_y = self.rect_pos_y + self.rect_height / 2
        self.rotate_origin = self.rotate_origin_x, self.rotate_origin_y
        self.angle = 135
        print('rect 1')
        with self.canvas:
            PushMatrix()
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0,197,68))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)
            PopMatrix()

    def rotate(self):
        self.canvas.clear()
        self.angle += 90
        if (self.angle > 315):
            self.angle = 225
        with self.canvas:
            PushMatrix()
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0, 255, 100))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)
            PopMatrix()
    def deflect_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            if not ball.collided[self]:
                vx, vy = ball.velocity
                if self.angle == 135:
                    ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(90)
                if self.angle == 225:
                    ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(270)
                if self.angle == 315:
                    ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(90)
                ball.collided[self] = True
        else:
            ball.collided[self] = False


    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.rotate()
            print(self.angle)

class Game1(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    object1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    object2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    def start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(5, 0)):
        Clock.unschedule(self.update)
        self.ball.center = 40, 380
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()
        self.object1.deflect_ball(self.ball)
        self.object2.deflect_ball(self.ball)

        if (self.ball.y < self.y+50) or self.ball.x <0:
            self.ball.velocity_y = 0
            Clock.unschedule(self.update)
            print('tested')
            self.serve_ball()

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

sm = Manager()

class ScreensApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreensApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `collide_widget()` method compares `pos` and `size` of the involved `Widgets`, the canvas drawing instructions have no effect on collision detection. So, I think you need to define your own method to detect a collision. Here is my attempt at such a method:

```
def collide_ball(self, ball):
    # get vector from center of rect to the ball
    to_ball = Vector((ball.x - self.rotate_origin_x), (ball.y - self.rotate_origin_y))

    # get x and y coordinates of above vector in rotated system
    x = to_ball.dot(self.rot_x_dir)   # along rect width
    y = to_ball.dot(self.rot_y_dir)   # along rect height

    # test for collision
    if x < -self.rect_width/2 - ball.size[0]/2:
        return False
    if x > self.rect_width/2 + ball.size[0]/2:
        return False
    if y < -self.rect_height/2 - ball.size[1]/2:
        return False
    if y > self.rect_height/2 + ball.size[1]/2:
        return False
    return True
```

This method should appear in each `Object`.

This requires the definition of `self.rot_x_dir` and `self.rot__dir`, which represent a coordinate system that is rotated with the `Object1` or `Object2` rectangle. These must be redefined wherever the rotation angle for the `Object` is changed. For example, in the `Object1.__init__()`:

```
    self.angle = 135
    self.rot_x_dir = Vector(1,0).rotate(self.angle)
    self.rot_y_dir = Vector(0,1).rotate(self.angle)
```

same code goes in the `Object2.__init__()`. Similarly, in the `rotate()` method:

```
def rotate(self):
    self.canvas.clear()
    self.angle += 90
    if (self.angle > 315):
        self.angle = 225
    self.rot_x_dir = Vector(1,0).rotate(self.angle)
    self.rot_y_dir = Vector(0,1).rotate(self.angle)
    with self.canvas:
        PushMatrix()
        self.rot = Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
        Color(rgb=(0, 255, 100))
        Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)
        PopMatrix()
```

Then, wherever you now use

```
self.collide_widget(ball)
```

replace it with:

```
self.collide_ball(ball)
```

Also, in your 'kv' adjust the drawing of the `PongBall`:

```
<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,1,1
        Ellipse:
            # adjust Ellipse position to center it
            pos: self.x - self.size[0]/2, self.y - self.size[1]/2
            size: self.size
```

Comment: It's really amazing @JohnAnderson, Can you please tell me a little bit more about collide_ball() method! ...and one thing apart from this field, how can I become such a skilled programmer as you are! ...really give me some tips please!

Comment: The `collide_ball()` method uses a coordinate system that is rotated by the same angle as the `Rectangle`, so that the `x` direction is always along the `width` of the `Rectangle`, and the `y` direction as along the `height`. The origin of that coordinate system is at the center of the `Rectangle` (your `rotate_origin`). So, calculating the `Vector` from the `rotate_origin` and using the `dot` product with the  `rot_x_dir` and `rot_y_dir` gives the (x,y) coordinates of the ball in the rotated coordinate system. determining if there is a collision is then simply comparing the bounds.